# onBackPressed() method doesn't work as expected in Android Navigartion Drawer

Tags: java, android, back-button, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

I'm trying to implement android navigation drawer. The problem is on my onBackPressed() method. when back button is pressed it redirect to my MainActivity. But I want to use it for go previous page from my present page.
I tried a lot but can't do. There is no error on my logCat.

so my onBackPressed() is like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return;
}
```

so now how to solve my problem.
For you're understanding there is my MainActivity code

```
package spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_barishal;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_chittagong;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_dhaka;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_home;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_khulna;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_main;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_mymensingh;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_rajshahi;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_rangpur;
import spurs.cafesoft.travelersguide.fragment.Fragment_sylhet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "ns.nayem350@gmail.com", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_main()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id==R.id.home){
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout,new Fragment_home()).commit();
    }

    else if (id == R.id.dhaka) {

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_dhaka()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.chittagong) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_chittagong()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.barishal) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_barishal()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.rajshahi) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_rajshahi()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.khulna) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_khulna()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.sylhet) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_sylhet()).commit();
    }else if (id == R.id.rangpur) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_rangpur()).commit();

    }else if (id == R.id.mymensingh) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_mymensingh()).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the transaction to the **backstack** when you replace your fragments. In that way you do not need the custom `onBackPressed` code and it should work fine.

The backstack is a stack that the android system uses to navigate back to previous system states, which is what you want when people pressing the back button.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Example using your code

```
 fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Fragment_mymensingh()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: It says addTobackStack() in FragmentTransiction can not be applied.
may be its a silly matter but I'm noob and help me plz what to do.

Comment: @TanvirDurlove sorry, you need to give it a tag parameter which can just be null. See updated answer.

Comment: What exact error you get? Did you also try using 4 lines like the first example, instead of everything in one line?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you're answer. I got it solve the problem as you're solution. Thanks again.